# SQL Multiple JOIN Query Not successful

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

**Background**

I have three tables: `Stock`, `PurchaseEntry`, and `SalesEntry`.

These tables have the fields `ProductName`, `MRP`, `LandinPrice` and `Qty` in common.

I need to join these tables in order to get `SUM(Qty)` in `PurchaseEntry` and `SalesEntry` with the same `ProductName`, `MRP`, and `LandinPrice` as `Stock`.

**Problem**

I tried using the following query, but the result was not as I desired.

`SUM(Qty)` of `PurchaseEntry` Gives some random results, whereas `SUM(Qty)` of `SalesEntry` is correct.

But when I use `JOIN` on `PurchaseEntry` alone individually, I get the correct values.

**Question**

How I can get the proper results, and what type of `JOIN`s should be used?

**SQL Code**

```
SELECT Stock.ProductName,
       Stock.MRP,
       Stock.LandinPrice,
       SUM(PurchaseEntry.TotalQty)
        AS PurchaseQty,
       SUM(SalesEntry.Qty)
        AS SalesQty  
FROM Stock
 JOIN PurchaseEntry
  ON Stock.ProductName = PurchaseEntry.ProductName
  AND Stock.MRP = PurchaseEntry.MRP
  AND Stock.LandinPrice = PurchaseEntry.LandinPrice
 JOIN SalesEntry
  ON Stock.ProductName = SalesEntry.ProductName
   AND Stock.MRP = SalesEntry.MRPPrice 
   AND Stock.LandinPrice = SalesEntry.LandingAmt
GROUP BY Stock.ProductName,
         Stock.MRP,
         Stock.LandinPrice
```

Solved:

I tried changing the Query myself. And I got the proper Output that i required. Below is that Query.

```
SELECT Stock.ProductName,
       Stock.MRP,Stock.LandinPrice,
       (SELECT SUM(PurchaseEntry.TotalQty) 
FROM PurchaseEntry 
WHERE Stock.ProductName=PurchaseEntry.ProductName 
AND Stock.MRP=PurchaseEntry.MRP 
AND Stock.LandinPrice=PurchaseEntry.LandinPrice) AS PurchaseQty,
       (SELECT SUM(SalesEntry.Qty) 
FROM SalesEntry 
WHERE SalesEntry.ProductName=Stock.ProductName 
AND SalesEntry.MRPPrice=Stock.MRP 
AND SalesEntry.LandingAmt= Stock.LandinPrice ) AS SalesQty
FROM Stock
GROUP BY Stock.ProductName,Stock.MRP,Stock.LandinPrice
```

Comment: If you have found the solution yourself, and none of the answers below are correct, then paste the solution as a new answer and marked it as answered.

Comment: sorry i couldn't do that. It says you have to wait for 8 hours to post answers yourself. May be since I am noob here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like

```
SELECT Stock.ProductName,Stock.MRP,Stock.LandinPrice, 
       (SELECT SUM(PurchaseEntry.TotalQty)
          FROM PurchaseEntry
         WHERE PurchaseEntry.ProductName=Stock.ProductName
           AND PurchaseEntry.MRP=Stock.MRP
           AND PurchaseEntry.LandinPrice=Stock.LandinPrice) AS PurchaseQty
       (SELECT SUM(SalesEntry.Qty)
          FROM SalesEntry
         WHERE SalesEntry.ProductName=Stock.ProductName
           AND SalesEntry.MRPPrice=Stock.MRP
           AND SalesEntry.LandingAmt=Stock.LandinPrice) AS SalesQty
  FROM Stock
```

Your existing query would have PurchaseQty multiplied by the number of sales and SalesQty multiplied by the number of purchases.  Of course I'm assuming that the combination of stock ProductName, MRP, and LandinPrice are unique.

Comment: I found this myself and have edited the question, please check. Anyway thanks

Comment: This too gave out an error while executing. "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'."

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Stock.ProductName,
Stock.MRP,
Stock.LandinPrice, 
SUM(PurchaseEntry.TotalQty) AS PurchaseQty, 
Sales.SalesQty
FROM 
Stock 
INNER JOIN PurchaseEntry ON Stock.ProductName = PurchaseEntry.ProductName AND Stock.MRP = PurchaseEntry.MRP 
AND Stock.LandinPrice = PurchaseEntry.LandinPrice
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(SE.Qty) AS 'SalesQty', SE.ProductName, SE.LandingAmt, SE.MRPPrice
    FROM SalesEntry SE INNER JOIN 
    Stock S ON S.LandinPrice = SE.LandingAmt AND S.MRP = SE.MRPPrice AND S.ProductName = SE.ProductName
    GROUP BY SE.ProductName, SE.LandingAmt, SE.MRPPrice
) Sales ON Sales.ProductName = Stock.ProductName AND Sales.LandingAmt = Stock.LandinPrice
AND Sales.MRPPrice = Stock.MRP
GROUP BY 
Stock.ProductName,
Stock.MRP,
Stock.LandinPrice
```

Comment: Sorry that too gave the same result.

Comment: That gave a error - Column 'Sales.SalesQty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.